# C: How pointers change address in memory and what does it imply

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

This a follow up from this question: [Why does a function which returns void not hold value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795728/why-does-a-function-which-returns-void-not-hold-value?noredirect=1#comment123372714_69795728). A user indeed suggested me to draw the pointers in the function `struct node * insert_front` and so the main questions is about that function and this line of code `head = new`

This is the minimum code needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* init(int value) {
    struct node* head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (!head) return NULL;
    head->value = value;
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

void insert_back(struct node* head, int value) {
    if (!head) return;
    struct node* temp = head;
    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = new;
    new->value = value;
    new->next = NULL;
    return;
}

struct node* insert_front(struct node* head, int value) {
    struct node* new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 
    new->value = value;
    new->next = head;
    printf("head->value: %d\n", head->value);
    printf("head->value ptr: %p\n", &head->value);
    printf("new->value: %d\n", new->value);
    printf("new->value ptr: %p\n", &new->value);
    
    head = new; 
    printf("head->value: %d\n", head->value);
    printf("head->value ptr: %p\n", &head->value);
    printf("new->value: %d\n", new->value);
    printf("new->value ptr: %p\n", &new->value);

    return new;
}

int main() {
    struct node* head = init(5);
    insert_back(head, 7);
    insert_back(head, 9);
    insert_back(head, 12);
    head = insert_front(head, 999)
return 1;
}
```

The output produced from `struct node* insert front(...)` is

```
    // after, new->next = head 
    head->value: 5
    head->value ptr: 0x(...)9e0
    new->value: 999
    new->value ptr: 0x(...)a50

    // after, head = new 
    head->value: 999
    head->value ptr: 0x(...)a50
    new->value: 999
    new->value ptr: 0x(...)a50
```

So we see that after `head = new` we have the same addresses for `head` and `new`. Given this I have two questions.

Firstly, have I understood correctly that, after `head = new` what happens is that we have moved the pointer which was pointing to the start of that region of memory used by the linked list (that is from `head`) to a new place in memory (that is where `new` is in memory)? Otherwise (or more technically, well-explained) what happened?

Secondly, when I print:

```
printf("&head->value: %p\n", &head->value);
printf("&head: %p\n", &head);
printf("head: %p\n", head);
```

I obtain

```
&head->value: 0x(...)9e0
&head: 0x(...)8c8
head: 0x(...)9e0
```

So, with `head` I am accessing the address of the region of memory I am pointing to and with `&head` the address of the pointer itself. But then why with `&head->value` I am accessing the same as with `head`?

Comment: `&head->value` is `&(head->value)`, it is the address of `head->value`, not `head`.

Comment: Read up on [operator precedence in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Alright, thanks, it makes sense now. What about the first part of the question?

Comment: Linked list doesn't occupy a "region of memory". Every node on its own occupies it's own "region", so the list as a whole is a chain of tiny regions, each living on their own. Pointer is exactly what the word says - it points. So `head = new` makes `head` point same place `new` points . `new` is not "in memory" in this meaning. `new` points to memory "region" you've got from `malloc`. And now `head` points there as well. If you print the pointer, you get the numeric address of a memory cell. That's what the pointer really is - an integer value. You can think it's an `id` of a memory cell.

Comment: This clarified many things, especially that 'Linked list doesn't occupy a "region of memory". Every node on its own occupies it's own "region", so the list as a whole is a chain of tiny regions'. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Firstly, have I understood correctly that, after `head = new` what happens is that we have moved the pointer which was pointing to the start of that region of memory used by the linked list (that is from `head`) to a new place in memory (that is where `new` is in memory)? Otherwise (or more technically, well-explained) what happened?

`head = new` does not move `head`. It changes the value of `head`. `head` is a pointer; its value is a memory address.

> But then why with `&head->value`  I am accessing the same as with head?

With C’s grammar,  `&head->value` is  `&(head->value)`, not  `(&head)->value`. It uses `head` to locate `head->value` and then takes the address of that. It does not take the address of `head` and then use it as a pointer to a structure.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Any insights about the first part of question as well?